# Best practice to size Autonomous Transaction Processing (ATP) (number of OCPUs) for APEX on ATP?

Tags: oracle-apex, sizing, oltp, oracle-autonomous-db

Since init parameters such as  “sessions” and “open_cursors” can not be modified in Autonomous Transaction Processing (ATP).  Is there any best practice guideline to size ATP (number of OCPUs) for APEX on ATP?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 settings for sizing Autonomous Database (ADW, ATP). Number of OCPUs and Terabytes of data.  All other settings are derived from those 2 settings. The number of sessions is a function of the number of OCPUs. You can query the database to see what settings are currently active based on your OCPU setting.

Additionally, note that auto-scale for CPU allows the database to consume more OCPU temporarily when required, but does not increase things like the number of sessions.

PS - I am a product manager for Oracle Autonomous Database (ADB)